# A constructor with a parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

I need only one instance of a class, so I have to use an object instead of a class. I also need to set some initial value chosen by a client, so I need to a constructor for an object, something like this:

```
object Object1(val initValue: Int){
  //.....
}
```

I can't use this exact code in Scala. How do I deal with that then?

Comment: It doesn't follow that you _have_ to use an object because you only _need_ one instance. Is it a _requirement_ that only one instance exists?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral, it is.

Comment: How do you make sure that you create it before you access it?

Comment: @ziggystar, why do I have to make sure about it?

Comment: Well, what happens if you access it before you create it?

Comment: @ziggystar what access, an object? it will be created automatically before I the first time access it. is that what you are asking about?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Make it a class, have the client construct it, give the value in the parameter
   Pro: Preserves immutability
   Con: Having only a single instance might be hard to manage
2. Add a variable for the param to the object, add a setter.
   Pro: You still have a singleton
   Con: There is mutable state now
3. Implement a [multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)
   Pro: Gives you (apparent) immutability and singleton (per param)
   Con: More code to implement

You could implement a multiton like this in scala:

```
class Object1 private (val initValue: Int) {
  // ...
}

object Object1 {
  val insts = mutable.Map.empty[Int, Object1]

  def apply(initV: Int) =
    insts.getOrElseUpdate(initV, new Object1(initV))
}
```

**UPDATE** You could also turn this into a "singleton with parameter":

```
object Object1 {
  var inst: Option[(Int, Object1)] = None

  def apply(initV: Int) = inst match {
    case Some((`initV`, i)) => i
    case Some(_) =>
      sys.error("Object1 already instantiated with different param")
    case None =>
      val i = new Object1(initV)
      inst = Some((initV, i))
      i
  }
}
```

Comment: the `apply()` in your "singleton with parameter" is not thread-safe.

Comment: Ah, yes, indeed (neither is the "multiton" by the way). I guess there is no one-fits-it all solution for making these thread safe. Most efficient would be to create and then to CAS, but that might initialize multiple times.

Comment: Solution 1 looks as good as using `var insts`, and initializing it later because anyways mutable kind of stuff is in use.

Comment: In my case, the apply method needs to return `this`.

Answer (score 5):

The object isn't created until you reference it, so you could do something like the following:

```
object Test1 extends App {
  var x = Console.readLine
  println(Object1.initVal)
}

object Object1 {
  val initVal:String = Test1.x
}
```

Comment: Why this is not generic is because many times the other entity(Test1 here) won't be an object necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather convention over configuration approach. But it is thread safe and adds obligatory initialisation requirement though a bit verbose:

```scala
    abstract class NetworkPusher() {
      private var networkAddress: String = ""
      def setNetworkAddr(addr: String) = networkAddress = addr
      def getNetworkAddr() = networkAddress
    }

    object NetworkPusherFactory {
    
      private var initOnceReady: NetworkPusher => Unit = _
    
      private lazy val initializedInstance = {
        val pusher =  new NetworkPusher(){}
        initOnceReady(pusher)
        pusher
      }
      def create(init: NetworkPusher => Unit): NetworkPusher = {
        initOnceReady = init
        initializedInstance
      }
    }
    
    object Main {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val networkAddr = "A.D.D.R" // args[0]
        val onePusher = NetworkPusherFactory.create(
          instance => instance.setNetworkAddr(networkAddr)
        )
        println(s"using ${onePusher.getNetworkAddr}")
      }
    }
```